visual studio 2019 instrumentation feature not working on already running process
visual studio 2019 16.9.7.
I am using the performance profiler to get profiling data on my c++ project.
I want to use the instrumentation feature, which I am able to use if I select the project as startUp project , or launch that exe through specifying the path.
But after selecting the option --> "attach to a running process" , the instrumentation checkbox gets disabled ( only CPU Usage , GPU usage, ETW are enabled) . Is it not possible to run instrumentation session on an already running process?
if possible then how to run it ?
I want the instrumentation to work on an already running process
